# Filling a 2d van with packages and backtracking

Tags: java, fill, backtracking

I have a van that needs to deliver packages to clients. The van has 800cm width and 370cm length. The van needs to be filled (without height) with packages from back to front. How do I even tackle this problem?! I made a 2D dimension with the final width and length.

```
public class Van {

public Van() {
    Dimension2D storage = new Dimension2D(800, 370);
}

// TODO: how the hell do I fill the van with backtracking
public void fillVan(ArrayList<Package> packages) {
    
}
```

Is there a way to subtract the width and length of the dimension when I add the package? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Grab a pen and a sheet of paper and draw it out. This should provide an idea of how to approach the problem in a naive way (i.e. just put in packages as they come until the van is filled). This will create "holes" in between the packages so the next step is to apply an optimization algorithm to try and reduce the number and size of those holes. That's where backtracking would come in, i.e. start at an earlier stage where less packages have been loaded already. - Since this is your task I'd assume you're already familiar with optimization algorithms, aren't you?

Comment: the delivery order should also be considered